# How to read Dictionary List from csv file in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I used following code to write a dictionary to a csv file.

```
with open('dict.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for key, value in dict.items():
        writer.writerow([key, value])
```

In "dict.csv" file:

accord [16, 32, 49] 
according [8, 37, 49, 50] 
accordingly [8, 37, 50] 
account [8, 10, 16, 19, 20, 23, 25, 33, 34, 47]

where accord, according, accordingly and account are the keys and [16, 32, 49], [8, 37, 49, 50], [8, 37, 50], [8, 10, 16, 19, 20, 23, 25, 33, 34, 47] are theri values respectively.
**Example:**
dict={'accord':[16, 32, 49]}


Now I want to read it back to dict. How To do that?

```
with open('dict.csv','r') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    dict ={rows[0]:rows[1] for rows in reader}
```

I tried using this code but it's giving index error.

IndexError: list index out of range.

and then I use the following code which is giving me this error.
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x97 in position 5: invalid start byte.

```
dict={}
csv_file=pd.read_csv('dict.csv')
for index, row in csv_file.iterrows():
    dict[row[0]]= row[[1]].tolist()
```

Comment: Are you sure this is your writing code? You would have empty lines interspersed because you missed to specify `newline=""`

Comment: Why use CSV? If you want to store a Dict there are better options to do that like JSON for example.

Comment: It does not look like CSV to me. Consider using [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You essentially created a self-desinged csv format.  You can read your input back in using string manipulation:

```
with open('dict.csv', 'w', newline="") as csv_file:
    csv_file.write("""accord [16, 32, 49] 
according [8, 37, 49, 50] 
accordingly [8, 37, 50] 
account [8, 10, 16, 19, 20, 23, 25, 33, 34, 47]""")

data = {}
with open('dict.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    for line in csv_file:
        key, *values = line.replace("[","").replace("]","").replace(",","").split()
        try:
            data[key] = list(map(int,values))  # try to convert to int list
        except ValueError:
            data[key] = values                 # else use string list
print(data)
```

Output:

```
{'accord': [16, 32, 49], 
 'according': [8, 37, 49, 50], 
 'accordingly': [8, 37, 50], 
 'account': [8, 10, 16, 19, 20, 23, 25, 33, 34, 47]}
```